# Как сохранить итератор, удаляя элемент из дерева?

Tags: c++, итераторы

У меня возникла проблема с итераторами.
Что делать если у меня имеется итератор для древа, и имеется потребность реализовать функцию erase дабы начать удалять узлы древа `от first до last`?

Проблема в том, что у меня в итераторе имеется указатель на конкретный элемент древа, и функции итератора активно с ним работают.

Но если удалить узел на который сейчас указывает итератор то ссылка перестает быть активной,весь `for`  идет коту под хвост, и оператор инкремента ++ не может перейти к следующему узлу.

Не могли бы вы мне подсказать как решить данную проблему?

P.S.  в случае необходимости, прикреплю примеры кода итератора и удаления элемента древа.

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке очень распространены ситуации, когда удаление элемента делает итератор невалидным... Действуйте по-другому, не пытаясь удалять элементы по олдному через итератор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возвращайте из `erase` итератор на элемент, следующий за удалённым, таким образом Вы всегда будете иметь возможность продолжить обход дерева.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, проверил ваш вариант. Он не подходит, мне методичке erase должен быть аналогичен erase в map, а значит возвращать воид.

Comment: @Demolver, это он раньше возвращал `void`, теперь возвращает [`iterator`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать рекурсивную функцию. Что-то вроде такого:

```
void deleteItems(Tree& tree, Item* itemToDelete, const Item* lastItem)
{
   if (itemToDelete != lastItem) {
      deleteItems(tree, itemToDelete->nextItem(), lastItem);
   }
   tree.deleteItem(itemToDelete);
}
```